# Beamer-bibtex multiple authors

Tags: beamer, bibtex, texworks

I have been trying to include some references in beamer but the result does not look good at all if there are three authors involved. For instance, with this bibtex entry

```
@Article{boudt2012gaussian,
  Title                    = {The Gaussian rank correlation estimator: robustness properties},
  Author                   = {Boudt, Kris and Cornelissen, Jonathan and Croux, Christophe},
  Journal                  = {Statistics and Computing},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {471--483},
  Volume                   = {22},

  Publisher                = {Springer}
}
```

the result using `\cite` and bibliographystyle `plainnat` looks like

[image]

which is quite long and distracting. It should normally have the first part only and not include all three authors! Is there perhaps another method here that leads to more elegant results?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)